# jquery block <select> to first option

Tags: jquery, select

I've a code like this:

```
<select name="aa">
    <option>a</option>
    <option>b</option>
    <option>c</option>
</select>
```

There is a way to stop opening select of all my form and make show only first select in this example only *a*?

Thanks in advance
ciao *h*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

remove all other options with the `:gt(0)` filter `(0)` is the index like this:

```
 $("select[name='aa'] option:gt(0)").remove();
```

or disable them like this:

```
 $("select[name='aa'] option:gt(0)").attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

and select an item with the `:eq(0)` filter `(0)` is the index like this:

```
 $("select[name='aa'] option:eq(0)").attr("selected", "selected");
```

the reverse can be done with a `:not` filter:

```
$("select[name='aa'] :not(option:gt(0))").attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

or a `:lt` filter:

```
$("select[name='aa'] option:lt(1)").attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

just assign an empty string  `.attr("disabled", "");` or `.attr("selected", "");` to remove an attribute setting.

**[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/r9a7S/)**

to flip/flop values I think you need a second (hidden) select:

**[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/r9a7S/2/)**

```
// hide items
var src = $("select[name='aa'] option:eq(0)");
var tar = $("select[name='ab']").hide();

tar.append(src.clone())
src.remove();


//reshow items:
src = $("select[name='ab'] option:eq(0)");
tar = $("select[name='aa']")

tar.prepend(src.clone())
src.remove();
```

Comment: @haltman Maybe you could use hide() and show() instead of remove()

Comment: IIRC some browsers (IE?) doesn't support hiding/showing `option`s.

Comment: @RoToRa, indeed ;)that is why you have to remove them, not hiding.

Answer (score 1):

what? you mean choose the default option? Try using the selected attribute on the a option

```
<option selected>a</option>
```

or to make an option unselectable:

```
<option disabled>a</option>
```

Comment: No I need a different thing, I need to block possibility to show *b* *c*, thanks you for answering.

Answer (score 1):

you can do this:

```
$("select[name='aa']").val($("select[name='aa'] option:first").val());
```

Answer (score 1):

you could disable the ones that you don't want to be able to be selected or you could alter their css display like :

```
$('select[name="aa"] option').not(':first').css('display','none');
```

if you want to automatically set a "default" value and do not let anyone change it, you could set the value of the first one and then disable the whole select element so that nobody changes it:

```
$('select[name="aa"]')
    // set the value of the first option
    .val($('select[name="aa"] option:first').val())
    // disable the select element so that no one can alter it's value
    .attr('disabled','disabled');
```